# Are my sequential random numbers correlated?

Tags: random-variable, covariance, uniform-distribution

Say I want to generate $n$ random numbers $Y_i, i = 1, ... n$, where $X_i \in [1,..n]$ is my i.i.d. uniform random source
and $Y_i$ are drawn sequentially:

$Y_0 = X_0$

$Y_i = (Y_{i-1} + X_i)\; \text{mod}\;  n$,

where mod is the modulus..
Then $cov(Y_i, Y_j) = 0$ should be true from my intuition, because any number is still equally as likely.

How would I go about showing this?
I had started like this
$$cov(Y_1, Y_0) = E[Y_1X_0] - E[Y_1]E[X_0] = E[(X_0 + X_1)X_0] - E[X_0 + X_1]E[X_0] = E[X_0^2] + E[X_1]E[X_0] - (E[X_0]^2 +E[X_0]E[X_1]) = E[X_0^2] - E[X_0]^2 = V(X_0)$$

Then I, however, realised that I would have to incorporate the whole modulus part and was unsure as to how..

Comment: Consider showing a stronger result: $Y_{i-1}$ and $Y_i$ are *independent.*  By making the statement stronger, it might seem one would have to work harder, but the opposite is true: by forcing our attention on something more fundamental, we are quickly directed to consider the fact that the joint distribution of $(Y_{i-1},Y_i)$ is invariant under independent permutations of the values of the components. (This is where the uniformity assumption is seen to be essential.)  The result is immediate.

Comment: Ok, so instead I should see it this way: $P(Y_0=a, Y_1=b)=P(Y_0=a)P(Y_1=b|Y_0=a)$ and because $P(Y_1=b|Y_0=a)$ is also uniform, it follows.. thanks!